# Uncommon Plants in Northern Argentina (Misiones)

Tags: plant-recommendations

A friend of mine has a little plantation in Argentina, Misiones. It's kind of a small rain forrest.

I would like to bring him some seed that would grow there and that he can't get there from every florist. I was thinking of a tree, medical plants or vegetables.

Any ideas?

Comment: given the number of problems worldwide concerning introduced plants which have become invasive this deserves serious thought.